# Apache mod_rewrite: rewrite HOSTNAME without redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It's clear to me how to perform a rewrite in apache using [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and I can rewrite the path *without* returning a redirect, but can I also rewrite the hostname without returning a redirect?

(I desire for the application that receives the request to make use of a particular hostname, but I don't want API users to need to follow any redirects.)

The **Absolute URL** section of the [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says something which makes it appear that a change of hostname will return a redirect be default:

> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL.

Comment: Could you please do add sample(examples only near to your actuals)  of URL like from which URL TO which URL you want to rewrite for better understanding of question please, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks, if a request comes in for https://example.org/mypath, I wish for the request to be handled by the same host as if it were for https://example.net/mypath. (Both requests should go to the same application on the same machine. If the request is for `example.org`, then apache should tell the application that the HOST header is actually `example.net` instead of `example.org`.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, at this point, I'm using a reverse proxy and manually overriding the Host HTTP header:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName old.domain.org
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPassMatch   ^/ https://new.domain.org/
  ProxyPassReverse ^/ https://new.domain.org/
  ProxyPreserveHost off
  RequestHeader set Host new.domain.org
  Header set Host old.domain.org
</VirtualHost>
```

...but I'd like to accomplish my goal with `mod_rewrite` so that I can make use of an `<If>` block.